# How to define the typing speed of input (Make it slower)

Tags: input, text, printing, adb, sleep

I have this code to input some text via adb shell. However, it is typing very fast and more than 60% of the runs 1 letter is missing because it was typing too fast.

So i need to know how to define  the typing speed of the device.shell('input') command.

The time sleep is a regular delay, has nothing to do with the question.

```
print(content)
device.shell('input text "{}"'.format(content), )
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import subprocess

content = "your_text_to_input"

# Define a function to input text with controlled typing speed
def slow_input_text(text, delay_between_characters=0.1):
    for char in text:
        subprocess.run(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'text', char])
        time.sleep(delay_between_characters)

# Call the function to input text with controlled typing speed
slow_input_text(content, delay_between_characters=0.1)

time.sleep(2)  # Regular delay
```

Comment: subprocess.run(['adb', 'shell', 'input', 'text', char]) - disconnects the device, restarts adb demon and continues with the tasks without any input, so calling the event was basically just a disconnect button

Comment: As for each character an own `adb shell`connection is established the waiting time will be way more than the specified `delay_between_characters`. It would be better to establish `adb shell`once and then just send the `input`commands for each character.

Comment: That would work but the input is a variable from a line of a txt file so i can't just wrtite 5 commands containing each letter sperately, also i mean i already establish an adb conenction before in my code so when i start a subprocess of course it shuts down the current one, can i somehow define the typing speed while preserving the previous connection?